# Find variance of an estimator

Tags: probability, distributions, mathematical-statistics, variance

Let X1,X2..,Xn a random sample from a population X having distribution function

$f(x;θ) = θx^{θ - 1}$   if 0 < x < 1

Where θ > 0 is a parameter. Is the estimator $θ = \frac{x̄}{1 - x̄}$ of θ a consistent estimator of θ?

My problem is to find the variance of θ. I know that the variance of a function is quite difficult to obtain. I tried the following:

$\frac{x̄}{1 - x̄} = x̄ (1 - x̄)^{-1} = x̄ - x̄^0 = x̄ - 1$

$Var(x̄ - 1) = Var(x̄)$

And then there is no problem to calculate the variance of the sample mean, but I think this reasoning is wrong.
Can I have an hint?

Comment: $\theta$ does not have a variance, because it's not a random variable.  $\bar x$ has a variance that, as usual, is $1/n$ times the variance of any of the $X_i.$ Thus, all you need to compute is that variance (which is an elementary integral).

Comment: @whuber Sorry but I didn't understand. I know theta doesn't have a variance, I have to calculate the variance of the function that is equal to theta. I know how to calculate the variance of the sample mean, but here there is a function with the sample mean, so how can II calculate the variance? Using the same function but instead of taking the sample mean I take the variance of the sample mean?

Comment: You should put a "hat" symbol on top of the estimator $\hat{\theta}$. There is an arithmetic error in your calculation here  $x̄ (1 - x̄)^{-1} = x̄ - x̄^0 = x̄ - 1$. For example, suppose $ x̄ =2$. Then, $x̄ (1 - x̄)^{-1} =2/(1-2)=-1$ but $ x̄ - 1=2-1=1$.

Comment: @JohnL sorry I didn't know how to put the hat on theta. So I have simply to transform ̄ into Var(̄) in the function?

Comment: There's an error in my calculation, too. 2/(1−2)=−2.

Comment: I would first find the mean and variance of $\bar{x}$ then use the delta method to find the asymptotic distribution of the estimator.

Comment: @JohnL I think we didn't do the delta method.., there is another way to know only if that function for n -> inf = 0?

Comment: show the mean squared error converges to 0

Answer (score 1):

To show $\hat{\theta}$ is consistent, first show that $\bar{x}$ is a consistent estimator of $\tau=\frac{\theta}{1+\theta}$.  Then, use the [continuous mapping theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Consistent_estimator#Establishing_consistency) to show that $\hat{\theta}$ converges in probability to $\frac{\tau}{1-\tau}=\theta$.

If you have not learned the continuous mapping theorem, you could also prove it is consistent directly if you have learned Chebyshev's Inequality. You can take $n$ large enough so that $\bar{x}$ is close to $\tau$ with high probability. Then, find the smallest and largest values that $\hat{\theta}$ could be given those bounds on $\bar{x}$. Take $n$ large enough to make $\hat{\theta}$ close enough to $\theta$ with high probability. That is a sketch of how to prove it directly.

To find the asymptotic variance of $\hat{\theta}$, the only way I know in this case is to use the delta method.